# A Progressive Web App in the Django, where i put the files?

Tags: django, progressive-web-apps

I have two files for my PWA, service-worker.js and manifest.json, but i not know or to put in the django project, at the root of project ?

There is no tutorial that explains well for Django...

This is content of service-worker.js :
https://paste.ee/p/c5Fme

This is content of manifest.json :
https://paste.ee/p/LKxOa

And in the template base.html : https://paste.ee/p/bj5wz

In terms of content, everything is ok?
so.. i need help for the place of files. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Put it inside of app templates folder, Ex: `yourapp/templates`